# Error nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "udp" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy

Tags: nginx, dns, udp, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to redirect my udp (dns) traffic to my resolver working in the backend so I want to use nginx reverse proxy. The following is my file in `sites-available/proxy` which I symlinked to `sites-enabled/`

```
upstream dns {
        server localhost:4567;
        server 127.0.0.1:4567;
}

server {
        listen 53 udp;
        listen [::]:53 udp;
        server_name _;
        proxy_pass dns;
}
```

And I added in the `nginx.conf` file the following

```
stream {
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy;
}
```

When I run nginx I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "udp" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy:18
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I don't know why udp is not getting flagged as an incorrect setting. Any ideas?

Comment: Redirecting DNS that way is a bad idea, for many reasons, starting with the fact that DNS uses TCP and UDP and hence you are already breaking things. Otherwise `udp` was introduced in Nginx 1.9.13, do you have that version or later? More important: your question is offtopic here are not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

stream {} should be outside http {}
and also server_name is not supported inside stream.

Comment: thank you for the pointer, I got rid of server_name and the stream {} block is definitely outside of http {} but the same error still persists